# Will Ubuntu Studio 20.04 come prepackaged with the drivers for AMD Radeon RX580 gpus?

Tags: amdgpu, 20.04

I have found that AMD's drivers and support site is woefully behind the curve on Linux support.  So I am wondering if Ubuntu 20.04 will come with drivers for the RX580 built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently booted a live version of Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine with an RX580, and the built-in driver worked fantastically (didn't need to use `nomodeset` when booting, great performance and no screen tearing or anything) so unless something has changed between 18.04 and 20.04, I'd say you're good to go!